# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}$ for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

As the title states, I'm interested in the asymptotic behavior of $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}} , \alpha > \frac{1}{2}$$
for $n \to \infty $. Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \forall a\in (0,1)$
By comparison to integrals,
$$
\frac{1}{1-a}\Big((n+1)^{1-a}-1\Big)=\int_1^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^a}\le\int_0^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a}=\frac{1}{1-a}n^{1-a}
$$
So$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^a}=O(n^{1-a})$

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}\sim \ln n$

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642652), we can use the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to get the asymptotic expansion
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-a}=\zeta(a)+\frac1{1-a}n^{1-a}+\frac12n^{-a}-\frac{a}{12}n^{-1-a}+\frac{a^3+3a^2+2a}{720}n^{-3-a}+O(n^{-5-a})
$$
For $a\gt1$, this shows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-a}=\zeta(a)
$$
where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann Zeta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

The zeta function has a singularity at $1$, so we handle that case separately:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-1}=\gamma+\log(n)+\frac12n^{-1}-\frac1{12}n^{-2}+\frac1{120}n^{-4}+O(n^{-6})
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_1^n\dfrac1{k^a}~\simeq~\int_1^n\dfrac{dx}{x^a}~=~?$$

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something obvious :S