# what is asymptotic behavior of $\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt[\alpha] k}$

Tags: asymptotics, divergent-series

Asymptotic behavior of $$\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt[\alpha] k}$$

for $\alpha=1$? is $\ln k$ what about $\alpha > 1$ ?

the suggested link is for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ my question is about $ 0< \alpha < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988710/asymptotic-behavior-of-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-alpha-for-alpha?rq=1. Same question, see first answer

Comment: I assume the bounds on your sum are $1$ and $n$, and that you are looking at the behavior when $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** try a comparison between series and integral, using the fact that for $\alpha > 0$ the function $f\colon x\in(0,\infty)\mapsto \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}$ is decreasing.

- Specifically, for $a>0$ (and $\alpha\neq 1$), the sum will behave as
  $$
  \int_{1}^n \frac{dx}{x^{1/\alpha}} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}}}{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}} 
  $$
  *as long as you can ignore the constant term in the integration and the comparison between sum and integral*. It is clear that this will only happen when both the integral and the sum diverge, i.e. for $\frac{1}{\alpha} < 1$ here (or, equivalently, $\alpha > 1$).

But anyway, for $\alpha < 1$ the sum converges (it is a $p$-series), and you simply have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}.
$$

- For the case $\alpha=1$, this is the partial sum $H_n$ of the Harmonic series, whose asymptotic behavior is well-known:
  $$
  H_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \ln n
  $$

Comment: Regarding the standard asymptotic behavior of $H_n$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence. To see a detailed example of how to perform a comparison series/integral, see "Method 2" in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1489796/75808).

Comment: @OP: answer edited to better address the case $\alpha < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha=1
 $ we have the well known asymptotic for the [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=H_{n}\sim\log\left(n\right)
 $$ if $\alpha>1$ we have, using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{1/\alpha}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}1\cdot\frac{1}{k^{1/\alpha}}
 $$ $$=n^{1-1/\alpha}+\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t^{1/\alpha+1}}dt
 $$ and since $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)
 $ we have $$S=n^{1-1/\alpha}+\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{t^{1/\alpha}}dt+O\left(\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{t^{1/\alpha+1}}dt\right)
 $$ $$=\color{red}{\frac{\alpha n^{1-1/\alpha}}{\alpha-1}+O_{\alpha}\left(1\right).}$$ If $0<\alpha<1$ the series converges to $\zeta(1/\alpha)$.

Comment: A quick note (I had the same thing, more or less): the asymptotics you gave are somewhat vacuous for $\alpha < 1$, since then the first term of your expansion is $o(1)$, and the partial sum is actually equivalent to its limit (as the series converges) -- which is hidden in the $O_\alpha(1)$.

Comment: @ClementC. you are completely right. It works only with a divergent sum, so $\alpha>1$. Thank you for pointing out.