# Euler Maclaurin Formula to prove $\zeta(0)=-\frac12$ and $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, euler-maclaurin

This is a quick question regarding the analytic continuation of the Riemman Zeta function by application of the [Euler Maclaurin Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) and the evaluation of $\zeta(0)=-\frac12$ and $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ .

Choosing $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^s}$ in the second order Euler Maclaurin Formula we obtain

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac12+\frac{s}{12}-\frac{s(s+1)}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{P_2(x)}{x^{s+2}}\,dx \tag{1}$$

Where $P_2(x)$ is the second [Periodic Bernoulli polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Periodic_Bernoulli_polynomials). $(1)$ extends analytically the Riemann zeta function for $-1<\Re(s)$. Obviously, there is a simple pole @ $1$.

If we now set $s \to 0$ in$(1)$ we immediately get that

$$\zeta(0)=-\frac12 \tag{2}$$

Similarly, if we integrate by parts the integral in $(1)$, we get the third order Euler Maclaurin formula that extends  analytically the Riemann zeta function for $-2<\Re(s)$.

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac12+\frac{s}{12}+\frac{s(s+1)(s+2)}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{P_3(x)}{x^{s+3}}\,dx \tag{3}$$

Letting $s \to -1$ in $(3)$  we immediately obtain

$$\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12} \tag{4}$$

Apparently this procedure is all fine because we have extended the domain of the Zeta function to the right of the line $-2$ in the S-complex plane, excluding only the point $s=1$, and now it makes sense to ask what is $\zeta(0)=\, ?$ for instance.
Note also that by letting $s \to 0$ in $(3)$ we again recover that   $\zeta(0)=-\frac12$.

**My question** is: Is this procedure correct  and valid or there are any caveat that should be taken into account before we perform it, or some additional condition that should be added?

Comment: The approach works provided you also show that,
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{P_n(x)}{x^{s+n}} dx
$$
is $s-$analytic for $\Re s > -n+1$.  With this proviso you are in good shape.  Nor then do you need to say $s \to 0$ or $s \to -1$.  You'll  have shown the extended $\zeta(s)$ is analytic and so continuous at these points and you can simply evaluate the right side when $s = -1$ or $s=0$.

Comment: If the Bernoulli periodic function are bounded on all Reals, then the integral is convergent for all $\sigma+n>1$, where $\sigma=\Re(s)$.

Comment: As you say it is easy enough to see that the integral is convergent and not too hard to go further and show it is $s-$differentiable.  The proof of these statements, or at least an acknowledgement that you are using these facts, would make your argument complete.  You need to be sure the extended version of the $\zeta$ function is analytic in order to say that it is the unique analytic continuation.

Comment: @WADon Thank you!

Comment: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642652) might be useful.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for your answer. Question: Is it possible to recover $\zeta(0)=-\frac12$ and $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ from $\zeta^\ast(z)$? Thank you again!

Comment: @Ricardo770: Yes. As the answer to this question is too long for a comment, I have added it as an answer, and I have extended the results to $\zeta(-4)$.

Comment: $$\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$$ does it mean that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N 1=\lim_{N\rightarrow +\infty}N=-\frac{1}{2}$$ ?

Comment: Riemann showed that a non converging series can be rearranged to get any number, in particular here 1/2=1/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @WADon if we manage to prove that the integrals in $(1)$ and $(3)$ above are finite, the analytic continuation is valid. So, I found an article (see below) where the author proves that the Bernoulli Polynomials on the interval $[0,1]$ satisfy the following inequalities for $k \geq 1$:

$$|B_{2k}(x)|\leq |B_{2k}| \,\,\text{and}\,\,|B_{2k+1}(x)|\leq(2k+1) |B_{2k}|.$$

Therefore we can prove that the two integrals  are indeed finite:

$$
\left|\int_1^\infty \frac{P_2(x)}{x^{s+2}}\,dx\right| \leq \frac12 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{\sigma+2}}\,dx=\frac12 \frac{1}{\sigma+1}<\infty\\
$$

For $\Re(s)=\sigma$ and $\sigma>-1$

and

$$
\left|\int_1^\infty \frac{P_3(x)}{x^{s+3}}\,dx\right| \leq \frac12 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{\sigma+3}}\,dx=\frac12 \frac{1}{\sigma+2}<\infty\\
$$

For $\Re(s)=\sigma$ and $\sigma>-2$

- D. H. Lehmer, On the maxima and minima of Bernoulli polynomials, Amer. Math. Monthly, v. 47
  (1940), pp. 533-538.

Comment: Something is wrong with your inequalities. What do you mean by $\leq$ when $s$ in not real? You need to use absolute values, triangle inequality and then use $|x^{s}|=x^{\Re s}$.

Comment: You are right, it should be $\sigma$ instead of $s$, I´ll fix it, thank you

Comment: You still missed the absolute values, I added them. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642652), and computed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1427571), for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt-5$, the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula says that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^z}=\zeta_n(z)+\frac1{1-z}n^{1-z}+\frac12n^{-z}-\frac{z}{12}n^{-1-z}+\frac{z(z+1)(z+2)}{720}n^{-3-z}\tag1
$$
where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\zeta_n(z)=\zeta(z)$.

If we set $z=0$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n1=\zeta_n(0)+n+\frac12\tag2
$$
If we let $n\to\infty$, we get $\zeta(0)=-\frac12$.

If we set $z=-1$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk=\zeta_n(-1)+\frac12n^2+\frac12n+\frac1{12}\tag3
$$
If we let $n\to\infty$, we get $\zeta(-1)=-\frac1{12}$.

If we set $z=-2$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\zeta_n(-2)+\frac13n^3+\frac12n^2+\frac16n\tag4
$$
If we let $n\to\infty$, we get $\zeta(-2)=0$.

If we set $z=-3$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\zeta_n(-3)+\frac14n^4+\frac12n^3+\frac14n^2-\frac1{120}\tag5
$$
If we let $n\to\infty$, we get $\zeta(-3)=\frac1{120}$.

If we set $z=-4$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=\zeta_n(-4)+\frac15n^5+\frac12n^4+\frac13n^3-\frac1{30}n\tag6
$$
If we let $n\to\infty$, we get $\zeta(-4)=0$.

Comment: thank you for your answer , very nice as always. $(+1)$!