# How to calculate convergence of a series related to the Euler's constant?

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I understand that

$$
\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r} \approx \int_{1}^n \frac{dx}{x} = \log n 
$$

I would like to verify whether the following holds true as well, for a series that is related to the above series:

$$
\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^{1/2}} \approx (log n)^{1/2} 
$$

I am doubtful whether this will work though.  I tried various ways to verify this but I am probably not using the correct fundamental properties required here.  Any guidance on how to calculate
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^{1/2}} 
$$
will be very helpful.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You might double check whether this has already been asked on MSE; for example, it looks to me like [**MSE 642617**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642617/euler-maclarurin-summation-formula-and-regularization?noredirect=1&lq=1) is related.

Comment: your approximation must be $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^{1/2}}\approx \int_{1}^n \frac1{x^{1/2}}\,d x=2\sqrt{n}-2$ instead of what you wrote

Comment: the sum is approximately  $2 \sqrt n  + \zeta(1/2) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt n}$   where $\zeta(1/2) = -1.4603545088095868128894991525152980125...$

Comment: Thank you!  I will work through this...