# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn}t^{s-1}dt$ for positive integers $n,k$ and $0<\Re s<1$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, fractional-part, mobius-inversion

Denoting  $\{x\}$ the fractional part function, and $k\geq 1$ and $n\geq 1$ integers, I've interested in a closed-form for the integral in this

> **Question.** What's about closed-form for the integral 
>   $$\int_0^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn}t^{s-1}dt,$$ for $0<\Re s<1$? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if this integral is well known. See below what is my motivation (do calculations, perhaps artificious from an integral representation of the Riemann Zeta function), and **this attempt**:

*First,* the integral is convergence for integers $k\geq 1$ and $n\geq 1$, because using absolute convergence one gets from the inequality (and the appendix) that our integral is convergent for $$ \left|  \int_0^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn}t^{s-1}dt\right|\leq  \int_0^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}t^{\Re s-1}dt,$$ when $0<\Re s<1$.

*Secondly,* following the hints of solutions in [2] for some integrals that likes to the integrand in the **Question** (see [2] if you want in the section References in the appendix), I believe that I obtain $$\int_0^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn}t^{s-1}dt=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{u^{nk}}{(u+j)^{s+1}}du,$$ when $0<\Re s<1$.

*As, I've said I'm interested in compute closed-forms for such integral and after try more calculations from the approach in the appendix (that interchange some summation index to get an identity, if it is feasible). I understand that if you answer previous **Question** you satisfy an answer for this post, but feel free if you want add some remarks with the purpose to get such identities that I evoke.*

---

We know the formula (11) here in [MathWorld with reference to [1]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), that is the Mellin transform of this fractional part function $$ \left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\} =\operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right).$$ 
Then since $0\leq \left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}<1$ I've computed with Möbius inversion formula to get $$ \left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{kn}\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn},$$ and after combining with the cited Mellin transform by absolute convergence, for $0<\Re s<1$ $$-\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{kn}\int_0^\infty\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn}t^{s-1}dt.$$

**References:**

[1] Balazard, M. and Saias, E. *The Nyman-Beurling Equivalent Form for the Riemann Hypothesis.* Expos. Math. 18, 131-138 (2000).

[2] Furdui, *Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals*, Problems in Mathematical Analysis. Springer (2013). (I say hints to Problems likes 2.14 and 2.21.)

Comment: All users, if there are some mistakes in my claims or calculations explain those in your answer. If my result is right I am asking what's about a closed-form for such expression.

Comment: I've been thinking on this problem a bit the last few days. I don't claim that Mobius Transforms are my strong point, nor is any sort of work related to the Riemann Zeta. That being said, I'll continue thinking and playing around with this. Above all, I recommend editing your post. You have two questions there, and I would split them up. Leave your main one here, and the edit will bump the question to the front page. Then, make another post with the second question.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: Playing with formulas you don't understand is the exact opposite of doing some mathematics. So why do you think that $\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{kn}\left\{ \frac{1}{t} \right\}^{kn}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F_k(s) = s\int_0^\infty \{x\}^k x^{-s-1}dx = s \int_0^\infty \left\{\frac1t\right\}^k t^{s-1}dt$$

Show that $$\int_0^x \{t\}^kdt = \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor +\{x\}^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

[And that (where it converges)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$\zeta(s) = s\int_0^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx = \frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \{x\} x^{-s-1}dx, \qquad\quad F_1(s) =  -\zeta(s)$$

Integrating by parts 
$$F_k(s) = s(s+1)\int_0^\infty \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor +\{x\}^{k+1}}{k+1} x^{-s-2}dx 
 = s\frac{\zeta(s+1)+F_{k+1}(s+1)}{k+1}$$
i.e.
$$\boxed{F_k(s) = \frac{k}{s-1} F_{k-1}(s-1)-\zeta(s)= -\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \zeta(s-m)\prod_{l=0}^{m-1} \frac{k-l}{s-l-1}}$$

Comment: interesting **mathematical** exercice for you : add the domain of convergence to all those formulas

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and advice. You and users as previous moderator are the heart of this site. I will study all details.

Comment: @user243301 ok so what is the domain of convergence of $\int_0^\infty \{x\}^k x^{-s-1}dx, k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ ? and how do you prove that where it converges $\int_0^\infty \{x\} x^{-s-1}dx = -\zeta(s)$ ?

Comment: Few minutes ago I was editing a new post, now I will read your questions and answer those in some hours. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @user243301 No, you have to start from the beginning, at your level. So what is the domain of convergence ?

Comment: I've no idea how get the domain of convergence, I know that $ \left\{ x \right\} ^k=O(1)$ in the integrand, of course.

Comment: @user243301 if $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ both converge then $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. So again, read a real analysis course.

Comment: There is a typo in your second integral $\int_1^\infty$. Many thanks.

Comment: $\int_0^1\frac{O(1)}{x^{s+1}}dx=-\frac{1}{s}$ if $\Re s<0$, and $\int_1^\infty\frac{O(1)}{x^{s+1}}dx=\frac{1}{s}$ for $\Re s>0$. Thus I don't understand how get the domain of convergence. Are my claims rights?

Comment: $g(x) = \{x\} = \mathcal{O}(1)$ means that $|g(x)| < C$ for some $C$ so that $|g(x) x^{s-1}| < C x^{-Re(s)-1}$ and $\int_1^\infty |\{x\} x^{-s-1}|dx < \int_1^\infty C x^{-Re(s)-1}dx= \frac{C}{Re(s)}$ **when $Re(s) > 0$**

Comment: 2nd step (the most important) : proving that $\int_1^\infty |h(x)|dx$ converges $\implies \int_1^\infty h(x)dx$ converges

Comment: A $\text{Perfect}^{\text{Perfect}}$ explanation.

Comment: **lis un cours de maths.**

Comment: I delete previous comment to avoid mistakes about typos. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

We can derive a recursion for $f_n$ which is valid for $n\ge2$ and $1\lt s\lt n$:
$$
\begin{align}
f_n(s)
&=\int_0^\infty\left\{\frac1t\right\}^nt^{s-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^\infty\{t\}^nt^{-s-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\frac1s\int_0^\infty\{t\}^n\,\mathrm{d}t^{-s}\\
&=\frac ns\int_0^\infty\{t\}^{n-1}t^{-s}\,\mathrm{d}t-\frac{\zeta(s)}s\\
&=\frac nsf_{n-1}(s-1)-\frac{\zeta(s)}s\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
We can explicitly compute $f_1(s)$ for $0\lt s\lt1$ using $(1)$-$(4)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162426):
$$
\begin{align}
f_1(s)
&=\int_0^\infty\{t\}t^{-s-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_0^L\{t\}t^{-s-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}-\frac1s\int_0^L\{t\}\,\mathrm{d}t^{-s}\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\left(\frac1s\int_0^Lt^{-s}\,\mathrm{d}t-\frac1s\sum_{k=1}^Lk^{-s}\right)\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\left(\frac1s\frac{L^{1-s}}{1-s}-\frac1s\sum_{k=1}^Lk^{-s}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\zeta(s)}s\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{n!}$ and rearrange to get
$$
\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{n!}f_n(s)-\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(n-1)!}f_{n-1}(s-1)=-\frac{\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)}{n!}\tag{3}
$$
Summing $(3)$, we get
$$
\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{n!}f_n(s)-\frac{\Gamma(s-n+2)}{1!}f_1(s-n+1)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{\Gamma(s-k)\zeta(s-k)}{(n-k)!}\tag{4}
$$
Applying $(2)$ to $(4)$, we get
$$
\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{n!}f_n(s)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma(s-k)\zeta(s-k)}{(n-k)!}\tag{5}
$$
Simplifying $(5)$ gives
$$
f_n(s)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{s}{k}}\frac{\zeta(s-k)}{s-k}\tag{6}
$$

---

**Extension by Analytic Continuation**

The recursion $(1)$ computes $f_n(s)$ from $f_1(s-n+1)$ and the integral for $f_1(s-n+1)$ in $(2)$ converges when $n-1\lt\mathrm{Re}(s)\lt n$. The integral for $f_n(s)$ in $(1)$ converges for $0\lt\mathrm{Re}(s)\lt n$, is analytic, and agrees with $(6)$ for $n-1\lt\mathrm{Re}(s)\lt n$. By analytic continuation, $(6)$ holds for $0\lt\mathrm{Re}(s)\lt n$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. You and users as user1952009 are the heart of this site. I will study all details.

Comment: I don't understand your 1st step

Comment: and (when $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$) the result is a finite sum, as I wrote in my answer

Comment: The first step is substituting $\frac1t=k+u$ where $k$ is a non-negative integer and $u\in[0,1)$

Comment: @robjohn Did you read my answer ?

Comment: two possibilities : or your change of order of summation isn't valid, or your infinite series can be simplified in some way

Comment: @user1952009: I have reworked my answer. it is numerically the same as my old answer. In any case, what I get is a bit different. For example, $f_1(s)=-\frac{\zeta(s)}s$, and I think your answer says $f_1(s)=-\zeta(s)$. I've checked this numerically, and $f_1(s)=-\frac{\zeta(s)}s$ seems correct.

Comment: @robjohn my answer is correct, except possibly the last line when solving the recursion (feel free to correct it). Note that $F_n(s) = s f_n(s)$ where $F_n$ is mine and $f_n$ is yours. And it is not clear to me how you got a finite sum form your infinite series of yesterday. Did you look at $f_n(s)-f_{n-1}(s)$ ?

Comment: Many thanks for your improvements, now these answers are the best references.

Comment: @user1952009: I did notice that your answer for $F_1(s)$ was off by a factor of $s$ from $f_1(s)$. I did not realize that that was by design. I had thought your boxed formula was the answer to the question. I did not show how to derive the finite sum from my previous answer; I only stated they were numerically the same. In $(3)$, we use $u_n(s)=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{n!}f_n(s)$ and solve the recursion $u_n(s)-u_{n-1}(s-1)=-\frac{\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)}{n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\braces{1 \over t}^{kn}t^{s - 1}\,\dd t:\ ?.\qquad
> k,n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}\,,\quad\Re\pars{s} \in \pars{0,1}}$.

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\braces{1 \over t}^{kn}t^{s - 1}\,\dd t &
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ \mapsto\ 1/t}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{\infty}^{0}\braces{t}^{kn}\,\pars{1 \over t}^{s - 1}
\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\braces{t}^{kn}\, t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{t - \left\lfloor t\right\rfloor}^{kn}\, t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}

---

With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\ >\ 0}}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{N}\pars{t - \left\lfloor t\right\rfloor}^{kn}\, t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{t - 0}^{kn}t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t +
\int_{1}^{2}\pars{t - 1}^{kn}\, t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t + \cdots +
\int_{N - 1}^{N}\pars{t - N + 1}^{kn}\, t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{kn}t^{-s - 1}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{1}t^{kn}\, \pars{t + 1}^{-s - 1}\,\dd t + \cdots +
\int_{0}^{1}t^{kn}\, \pars{t + N - 1}^{-s - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{kn}\sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over \pars{k + t}^{s + 1}}\,\dd t
\end{align}

---

When $\ds{N \to \infty}$, it becomes:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\braces{1 \over t}^{kn}t^{s - 1}\,\dd t & =
\int_{0}^{1}t^{kn}\,\zeta\pars{s + 1,t}\,\dd t\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\zeta\pars{a,b}}$ is the
[Hurwitz Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

> So far, there are many representations of the *Hurwitz Zeta Function* which can be 'inserted' in the above result \eqref{1} to yield an expression as a series but a 'closed form' doesn't seem feasible at this time.
>   
>   In particular, CAS doesn't help at all, either.

Comment: Many thanks also to you for your great answers. Your aproach in very nice.

Comment: What do you mean with a closed-form ?

Comment: @user243301 Thanks. You're welcome.

Comment: @user1952009 As usual, it means something which can be expressed in terms of 'elementary functions' $\left(~\exp, \ln, \ldots~\right)$ and/or 'special' funtions like $\Gamma, \zeta, \mathrm{Bessel}\, \ldots$ or something else.

Comment: @FelixMarin  as usual :D did you read other answers ? You end up with an integral of $\zeta(s,a)$ whereas the answer (when $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$) is just a finite sum of $\zeta(s-m)$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. I read both of them. Your answer is quite fine.  My answer involves the Hurwitz Zeta Function $\zeta\left(\color{#f00}{\ldots},\color{#f00}{\ldots}\right)$ ( $\mathbf{two}$ arguments ) instead of the usual  Zeta function $\zeta\left(\color{#f00}{\ldots}\right)$ ( $\mathbf{one}$ argument ).  I'm pretty sure there is a conection between them but I didn't elaborated it further.

Comment: oops I meant $\int_0^\infty \{1/t\}^k t^{s-1}dt = \int_0^\infty \{x\}^k x^{-s-1}dx = \int_0^1 a^k \zeta(s+1,a)da$ that's trivial, so you are not on the right track with your answer