# Where does this asymptote for $H_n^{(k)}$ come from?

Tags: asymptotics, harmonic-functions, upper-lower-bounds, harmonic-numbers

@Claude Leibovici's answer to this [Math Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567123/limit-involving-generalised-harmonic-numbers) (it's the second answer) gives an asymptote for the generalised harmonic number $H_n^{(k)}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^k}$:

$$H_n^{(k)}=n^{-k}
   \left(-\frac{n}{k-1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)
   +\zeta (k)$$

Heuristically, this is an excellent fit. But can someone please tell me if this is a published result, and more importantly how it is derived?

Comment: It should follow from [Euler–Maclaurin summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: Hi @Greg Martin - please see my updated question here: <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563469/inequalities-to-give-bounds-on-generalised-harmonic-numbers>. Thank you.

Comment: @ Richard Burke-Ward Good and precise question. Here's a simple exact solution: we can easily derive this relation $H_{n}^{(k)} = \zeta(k) +\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}( \frac{d}{dn})^{k-1} H_{n}$. Then substituting the asymptotic expansion of $H_n$ immediately gives that of $H_{n}^{(k)}$. I suggest to reopen the question since IMHO the question is not a duplicate (and the solution given now here is even less so).

Comment: Hi @Dr Wolfgang Hintze, I am have voted this for reopening. I'll look forward to accepting your answer - but I'd appreciate a little more detail. How do you arrive at that initial relation? By 'asymptotic expansion of $Hn$', do you mean McLaurin series?

Comment: PS: I still think the other question is just a larger version of this one! And there are points available!

Comment: @ Richard Burke-Ward In the meantime I have posted my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3602985/198592