# Block sum of harmonic series and its dependence on term index

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics

Fix some constant $\delta>0$. Consider a harmonic series ${a_l = \dfrac{1}{l}}$.

Define the sequence $\{n_i\}$ as the following:
$n_1 = 0$ and $n_i = \inf \left\{k: \sum\limits_{l=n_{i-1}+1}^k a_l \ge \delta \right\}$ for $i\ge 2$.

Clearly $n_i - n_{i-1}$ indicates the amount of terms needed for the sum $\sum\limits_{l=n_{i-1}+1}^{n_i} a_l$ to be greater than $\delta$, and we expect that the number of terms contained in a block sum grows as terms in a harmonic sequence decrease.

My question is: can we give an asymptotic expression for $n_i$ or some approximate expression of $n_i$?

---

Additional comment: what if $a_l = \dfrac{1}{l^p}$ for some positive integer $p>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that
$$
\log n + \gamma  < \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\frac{1}{l}}  < \log n + \gamma  + \frac{1}{{2n}}
$$
for any $n\geq 1$ , where $\gamma$ is the Euler$-$Maclaurin constant (see, e.g., R. M. Young, Euler's constant, *Math. Gaz.* **75**, 187$-$190, 1991.). Thus,
$$
\sum\limits_{l = n_{i - 1}  + 1}^{n_i } {\frac{1}{l}}  = \sum\limits_{l = 1}^{n_i } {\frac{1}{l}}  - \sum\limits_{l = 1}^{n_{i - 1} } {\frac{1}{l}}  > \log n_i  - \log n_{i - 1}  - \frac{1}{{2n_{i - 1} }}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum\limits_{l = n_{i - 1}  + 1}^{n_i } {\frac{1}{l}} >\delta
$$
is definitely satisfied if
$$
\log n_i  - \log n_{i - 1}  - \frac{1}{{2n_{i - 1} }} \ge \delta ,
$$
i.e., if
$$
n_i  \ge n_{i - 1} e^{\delta  + \frac{1}{{2n_{i - 1} }}} .
$$
Regarding your additional question, you may proceed similarly by using
\begin{align*}
\zeta (p) + \frac{1}{{n^p }}&\left( { - \frac{n}{{p - 1}} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{p}{{12}}\frac{1}{n}} \right)  < \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{l^p }}}  \\ & < \zeta (p) + \frac{1}{{n^p }}\left( { - \frac{n}{{p - 1}} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{p}{{12}}\frac{1}{n} + \frac{{p(p + 1)(p + 2)}}{{720}}\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right),
\end{align*}
where $\zeta$ is Riemann's zeta function (see, e.g., my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3603164).

Comment: Thank you @Gary for your detailed answer. One quick follow-up question: you provided a sufficient condition for the sequence $\{n_i\}$ to have the desired bound. I do not see why it is also necessary.

Comment: I do not claim it is necessary. The two-sided inequality for the sum becomes pretty tight for large $n$. I would calculate the first few $n_i$'s by hand and compute the rest by the condition I obtained. In this way, I belive, you can obtain a reasonable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

From the asymptotic expression of the Harmonic numbers,

$$H_n\sim\log n+\gamma$$ means that

$$n\approx e^{H_n-\gamma}.$$

To increase the sum in constant steps, $n$ must grow exponentially.

Comment: Hi Yves. Can you please point me to some reference so that I can understand your answer better? Many thanks.

Comment: @Leonardo: Harmonic numbers.